# How to link math.stackexchange account to new mathoverflow account.

Tags: support, user-accounts, mathoverflow

I've been using math.stackexchange for some time, but say I would like to use mathoverflow how can I "transfer" this account over to MO? I tried logging in with the email address I use for stackexchange in MO but it says that I have to create a new ID.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible. Start a new account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When this question was asked, MathOverflow was not a part of the StackExchange network, so accounts there were not connected to StackExchange accounts, such as your Math.SE account.

Comment: I wonder whether this answer should be updated to reflect the fact that MO is now part of SE network. (Although I doubt that someone will be asking this specific question again, since now that association of accounts happens more-or-less automatically when signing to a new site. The question might have been more interesting for MO users after the transition, but probably most of them already did what was necessary. (I guess [this thread](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/15/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-old-mathoverflow-account) was about linking old MO accounts to new SE accounts.0

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Maybe start a new meta-thread about what to do with old meta-questions whose answers are no longer relevant.  This answer cannot be un-accepted, and it doesn't feel right to significantly alter it.  And I'm certain that this is not the only meta-question whose (accepted) answer has become incorrect with the passage of time.

Comment: @ArthurFischer You wrote: *it doesn't feel right to significantly alter it.* In my opinion, it is perfectly ok to change the answer if some facts in it have changed. In this particular case, the opinion of Isaac (as the post owner) is probably more relevant than mine. If you think that it is important enough issue (or if you want a better place to discuss this problem) feel free to open a new question. (At the moment I know only about this case, so I am not sure whether it is important enough to start a new discussion.)

Comment: @Martin: I know of some other examples, but I think my original response must have been made in a state of coffee withdrawal because although I noticed that the OP was no longer active on math.SE, it never occurred to me to check Isaac.  D'oh!  (If you want, flag some comment here when you've read it, and I'll clean up the meta-meta-discussion consisting of all but your original comment.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer:  I think there used to be a close-as-no-longer-relevant reason, but I'm not seeing it at a glance—that would be my preferred over-all solution for dealing with meta questions that are completely irrelevant.  As to this specific question, feel free to edit the answer to make it currently-accurate—I don't have the specific knowledge of the current account-merging process to properly edit it.

Answer (score 4):

According to the MathOverflow history page [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/753/history-of-mathoverflow), MO joined the StackExchange network on June 24, 2013. Thus, it is now automatic. (You can click the SE link at the top left of the page and then click MathOverflow and sign up.)